# Responsive search box and elements inside a shell

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble creating a responsive box with a search function for a mobile site. I am planning on adding jquery functions to this website so I want to to create an outer shell, then put inside the shell a unique logo element, and a unique search element. When I run this code, the search box has issues with height. I would like the height to be responsive, not static.

HTML:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>

    <style type="text/css">
*{
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.outer-top{
    border: 1px solid black;
    }

.logo {
    border:1px solid black;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    width:25%;
    height: 15%;
    }
.searchbar {
    border:1px solid black;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    width:75%;
    height:15%;
    }

    </style>

    <div class="outer-top">
            <div class="logo">
                <p>logo</p>
            </div>
            <div class="searchbar">
                <input type="text" name="search"><input type="submit" value="Search" class="sbutton">
            </div>
    </div>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.outer-top{
   border: 1px solid black;
   height:400px;
}
```

Your outer-top div need to have a height specified. In my own case, mine is 400px

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response unfortunately, I still have a responsive height issue with this code. ):

Comment: @user3435505 the height of the text box or search bar?

Comment: the container for both, the class searchbar needs to have the same height as the class logo.

Comment: @user3435505 I have edited my answer. If it works for you, accept it as your answer.